# Issue installing Canonical Livepatch - Error Message

Tags: snap, ubuntu-core, canonical-livepatch

I am facing an issue while trying to install Canonical Livepatch on my Ubuntu system. The error message I am encountering is as follows:

$ sudo snap install canonical-livepatch
error: cannot perform the following tasks:

- Run hook connect-plug-etc-update-motd-d of snap "canonical-livepatch" (run hook "connect-plug-etc-update-motd-d": cannot locate base snap core: No such file or directory)

In my efforts to troubleshoot, I also tried refreshing Core22, but encountered a related issue:

$ sudo snap refresh --beta core22
sudo snap refresh --stable core22
error: cannot perform the following tasks:

- Copy snap "core22" data (cannot find installed snap "core22" at revision 1122: missing file /snap/core22/1122/meta/snap.yaml)
  snap "core22" has no updates available

I believe these problems might be connected. Has anyone faced similar challenges or has insights into resolving this? Your help is much appreciated.

Comment: What system are you attempting to install livepatch for?  Livepatch only works on the LTS releases.

Comment: My system is Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS. It was already installed correctly but I probably did something I shouldn't have done and it was deconfigured.

Comment: I'd be inclined to `snap remove --purge canonical-livepatch` then also remove `core22`. It might be you have other snaps which depend on `core22` though. Once removed, you should be able to reinstall it.

Comment: Understood. I'm considering following your suggestion to address the issue with "core22." Before proceeding, I'd like to confirm if removing the snaps depending on "core22" would cause any issues during the process. Here's the list of snaps depending on "core22": "firefox," "gnome-42-2204," "snap-store," and "snapd-desktop-integration."Would there be any inconvenience in removing these snaps before proceeding with the removal of "core22"? I appreciate your guidance on potential issues that might arise before following the mentioned steps.

Comment: Just be aware if you `--purge` a snap, the data associated with it is lost. So if you purged firefox you'd lose your browser favourites etc.

Comment: I get this error:I get this error when I want to uninstall the snaps that depend on core 22:

Zephyrus-G14-GA401IV-GA401IV:~$ sudo snap remove firefox gnome-42-2204 snapd-desktop-integration
2024-02-01T08:12:11-05:00 INFO Waiting for conflicting change in progress...
error: cannot perform the following tasks:
- Remove data for snap "firefox" (3728) (unlinkat /var/snap/firefox/common/host-hunspell/es_CL.dic: read-only file system)

It seems to me that it is because the snaps are read-only, how could I proceed?